# Unexpected fgets behavior on modified file

Tags: c++, buffering

Here is my code.

```
  char a[200], b[200];
  FILE* fp = fopen("a.txt", "a+");
  fprintf(fp, "abc\n");
  fflush(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fgets(a, 100, fp);
  sleep(5);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fgets(b, 100, fp);
  puts(a);
  puts(b);
```

The original content of "a.txt" is "abc".
I executed this program and manually changed the content of "a.txt" to "d" while the program was put to sleep.
Unexpectedlly, the char array `a` and `b` are both "abcabc\n" while I want the result of `b` to be "d".

I did more tests and the results are as follows:

1. If **fread** is used instead of **fgets**, the result of `b` will be "d".
2. If **fflush(fp)** is executed before **fgets(b)**, the result of `b` will be "d".
3. If "\n" is deleted in the function **fprintf**,  the result of `b` will be "d"(`a` is "abcabc").

I am confused by the above results and hope someone can explain.

My operating environment：g++ 4.8.5 -std=c++11, linux 3.10

Comment: I suspect buffering _"...The stream is fully buffered unless..."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen

Comment: In C `fopen` with `"a+"` *The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but output is always appended to the end of the file.* and *Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode) causes all subsequent  write  operations to this stream to occur at end-of-file...* [man 3 fopen](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)